# Symfony2 cache issue while setting session save path dynamically

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to set session save path dynamically in Bundle extension class

```
namespace AdminBundle\DependencyInjection;

class AdminExtension extends Extension{
...
   $sessionDir = $envDir . "session/store/$userDir/__sess";
   $container->setParameter("session.save_path", $sessionDir);
...
}
```

Symfony caches Extension class

```
$sessionDir = $envDir . "session/store/12345/__sess";
```

So it make sessionDir equal to directory of user who make first call.

**It works normal for first user but doesn't work for others.**

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem by writing my own **NativeSessionHandler**

```
class NativeFileSessionHandler extends NativeSessionHandler
{

    /**
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     */
    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
       ...
        ini_set('session.save_path', $envDir . "session/storefront/$userDir/__sess");
        ini_set('session.save_handler', 'files');
    }

}
```

**services.yml**

```
custom_file_session_handler:
    class: CoreBundle\Session\Handler\NativeFileSessionHandler
    arguments: [@service_container]
```

**config.yml**

```
framework:
   session:
        handler_id: custom_file_session_handler
```